# Creating a form out of relation based key, values in django

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have a django based application where I want to create a form out of key, value pairs from a model. The `Child' model consists of the following rows of data:

```
(<parent 1>, 'component 1', 'dummy content 1'),
(<parent 1>, 'component 2', 'dummy content 2'),
```

Here is are my models:

```
# models.py

class Parent(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Parent'
        db_table = "parent"

    title = models.CharField(max_length=28)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class Child(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Child'
        db_table = "child"

    parent = models.ForeignKey(Parent, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    key = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    value = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.parent
```

Following is the direct model to form mapping I am currently using for my other forms to keep it straight forward and simple

```
# forms.py
class MyForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Child
        fields = () # fields go here
```

Then I pass this form to my view. The view `page_view` takes `pk` of the parent, gets the parent and passes it to the form. The form is then passed on to the template `parent_view.html` via the view.

```
# views.py

@login_required
def page_view(request, parent_pk):
    parent = get_object_or_404(Parent, pk=pk)
    my_form = MyForm(request.POST, instance=parent)
    return render(request, 'parent_view.html', {
        'parent': parent,
        'my_form': my_form,
    })
```

In the template I render the form like this:

```
<!-- page_view.html -->
{{ my_form }}
```

However, I would also like to write the html for this manually to add any design changes locally. I would like the `forms.py` `MyForm` to construct a form from the model by collecting key, value pairs for the provided parent.

So it should render it like this:

```
<form action=''>
<label for='component_1'>component 1</label>
<textarea name='component_1' type='text'>dummy content 1</textarea>
<label for='component_2'>component 2</label>
<textarea name='component_2' type='text'>dummy content 2</textarea>
</form>
```

But I can't seem to get my head around how to handle that in the `MyForm'. I have looked around a couple of solutions over stackoverflow but none of them point me in the right direction for this problem. If anyone has any ideas I would highly appreciate. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

If there are multiple Child instances, then a single form will not be of much use, you will have to use a formset (a model formset to be precise).

As per the docs,

A formset is a layer of abstraction to work with multiple forms on the same page

```
# forms.py

# You can provide a text area widget for the field that you want to be displayed as a text area

class MyForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Child
        fields = () # fields go here
        widgets = {
            'field_name': forms.Textarea(attrs={'cols': 80, 'rows': 3}),
        }

ChildFormset = forms.modelformset_factory(Child, ChildForm, exclude=[], extra=0)
```

Then in your views, you can pass a queryset of all the objects that you want in your form

```
# views.py

from .forms import ChildFormset
@login_required
def page_view(request, parent_pk):
    parent = get_object_or_404(Parent, pk=pk)
    child_queryset = parent.child_set.all()
    if request.method == 'GET':
        child_formset = ChildFormset(queryset=child_queryset)
        return render(request, 'parent_view.html', {
            'parent': parent,
            'my_formset': child_formset,
        })
    else:
        child_formset = ChildFormset(request.POST, queryset=child_queryset)
        if child_formset.is_valid():
            for form in child_formset:
                 form.save()
                 # ... Do whatever else you want to do with the data
```

In your templates, you will then have to traverse through all the form objects in the formset. Then you can display them in whatever way you want to.

```
# parent_view.html

{{ child_formset.management_form }} 
{% for form in child_formset %}
    <div class="hidden">{{ form.id }}</div>
    {% for field in form.visible_fields %}
        {{ field }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

NOTE: The Foreign Key field will be displayed as a drop down for the user to select a parent object from the list of parent objects.

Comment: what does `parent.child_set.all()`. child_set.all() doesn't seem to a django model attribute and throws out error.

Comment: If you would have wanted to access the parent object from a child object, you could easily have used the '.' operator.  

But if you want to access child from parent, it is known as a reverse foreign key relation because you are traversing in the reverse direction. For this, you need to use child_set to get all the objects which have got parent as the foreign key.

If you provide the related name inside your model where you have defined the Foreign key, then instead of using child_set, you will use

    parent.related_name.all()

Comment: It's printing out the form in the template with your solution but instead of having the value from key, value as value of the field, it uses the pk of the child as value of the field `<input type="hidden" name="form-0-id" value="10" id="id_form-0-id">`

Comment: Also from management from, it doesn't show any dropdown, instead prints out this form: `<input type="hidden" name="form-TOTAL_FORMS" value="11" id="id_form-TOTAL_FORMS"><input type="hidden" name="form-INITIAL_FORMS" value="11" id="id_form-INITIAL_FORMS"><input type="hidden" name="form-MIN_NUM_FORMS" value="0" id="id_form-MIN_NUM_FORMS"><input type="hidden" name="form-MAX_NUM_FORMS" value="1000" id="id_form-MAX_NUM_FORMS">`

Comment: The management form is used by the formset to manage the collection of forms contained in the formset. So what you are displaying is exactly what the management form does. The drop down will be of the Foreign key in your form. Moreover, I am editing the answer to have the form.id as a separate field than all other fields. Maybe that can be of help

Comment: If not, then please explain the key value pair (a little more) so that it's a little more clear.

Comment: Basically, in my form, I am looking to have the `key` as label of the input field and `value` as value of the input field. So if in my table `child` (model: `Child`), I have the following `Child(pk=1,parent=1, key='key1', value='value1')` and  `Child(pk=2,parent=1, key='key2', value='value2')`. In my form i want to have `<label for='1'>key1</label><input name='1' value='value1' /> <label for='2'>key2</label><input name='2' value='value2' />` so that pk becames the name of the field and key becomes the label and value is the actual value inside the text field.